# Combine two Redis instances into a single instance with two dbs

Tags: redis

I have two Redis instances (or two respective dump.rdb files) and I would like to combine them into a single instance with two dbs, one for each respective initial instance.

I could do this using MIGRATE, but it is only available in Redis 2.6.0, which is not supported by my current Redis server.

Answer (score 9):

### EDIT

This answer is no longer accurate for newer versions of redis. Leaving the answer for historical reasons.

---

If you are willing to play around a bit with binary files, you can easily combine the two dump.rdb files into one.

Assumptions :

1. Each dump has just a single database - the default database
2. You are using Redis 2.4.x, and therefore the dump version is either 2 or 3

If you open the file in a hex editor, this is the format of the RDB file -

`REDIS000x FE 00 <actual data > FF`

Here -

- `000x` is the rdb version number. It will most likely be 0002 or 0003 in your case
- `FE` is the database selector, and `00` is the database number
- `<actual data>` is the key-value pairs in the current database. You can treat this as a binary blob for your current purpose.
- `FF` is the last byte in the file and indicates the end of the rdb file

So to merge the two rdb files, do the following -

1. Create a new destination file
2. Copy everything from the first file except the last `FF`
3. Copy two bytes `FE 01` to indicate start of second database
4. NOTE : If you are sure the two databases don't have duplicate keys, and you want to combine them into a single database, simply skip the two bytes `FE 01` mentioned above.
5. From the second file, skip the first 11 bytes - i.e. skip `REDIS000x FE 00`
6. Copy over the rest of the second file, including the last byte `FF`

You can now copy this new dump.rdb to the appropriate directory in redis and restart.

If you are interested, [here is complete documentation of redis dump file format](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-RDB-Dump-File-Format), but you don't need to understand all of it for this simple use case.

Comment: This answer is too old and may be misguiding. Now redis dump file no longer end with FF but with one byte of "FF" and an eight-byte of checksum. Watch out you don't truncate you rdb file wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique that I used to consolidate 4 Redis servers (running 2.4.x) into 2 (I, two times, combined 2 separate Redis instances (each with data in db0) into 1 containing two separate dbs):

1. Make the new instance, Foo, a slave of your instance A (i.e. edit `redis.conf` and use `slaveof`).
2. Once Foo finishes syncing from A, remove slaveof so it becomes master. All data will be in db0.
3. Use [redis-dump](https://github.com/delano/redis-dump) (Ruby library but has command line util) to export or dump all the data from instance B. This'll create a JSON file.
4. If the data was in db0 in instance B, you'll need to now edit the resultant JSON file from step #3. This is b/c you don't want to import B's data into Foo's db0 which now contains A's data.

   - redis-dump's format contains the source db for each key; thus, you'll need to edit the document to change the db from 0 to something else -- 1, 2, etc.
   - My JSON files were large, so I used sed: `sed -e 's/\"db\":0/\"db\":3/' orig.json > db_3.json`
5. Use redis-dump's `redis-load` command to import the JSON file containing the data from instance B into Foo.

   - If you edited the JSON file and changed the db so something different, such as 3, then you'll need to import the data into that db, i.e `<new.json redis-load -u host:port -d 3`
   - If you have sufficient data (I was importing GBs) it *might* take hours. You can speed things up by running this process on the same box as the target Redis instance (Foo).

Now you have a single Redis instance (Foo) with A's data in db0 and B's data in db1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of troubles with it , so I've created a python script that uses dump and restore.
It serializes one db to a dictionary object and picles it. With a different switch the picled file is loaded and the data is uploaded to other redis instance.

https://gist.github.com/romanmah/9664407