# How to put data in several Redis dump.rdb file together in short time?

Tags: redis

I have 3 dump.rdb file generated by different machine. I want to gather all data in 3 files into 1. Now I write a program to read from remote and write to the local dump.rdb but it really cost time. So I want to know if there's some other way.

Should I use master/slave way? I'm new to Redis. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools such as [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) or [redis-rdb](https://github.com/nrk/redis-rdb) to dump rdb to more friendly format. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. For backups, simply copying rdb is enough. And you can restore from it.

Comment: I found a same question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083432/combine-two-redis-instances-into-a-single-instance-with-two-dbs) and I'm trying the first method :-)