# Redis process was killed by OS, Is there a bug?

Tags: ubuntu, redis

The Redis process suddenly disappeared.

I tried to restart it, but was killed again(See following):

```
/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf
Killed
```

And following is the log content, no any exception.

> ```
> > [19724] 26 Nov 10:45:29.457 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.16
> > [19724] 26 Nov 10:46:13.172 * DB loaded from disk: 43.715 seconds
> > [19724] 26 Nov 10:46:13.182 * The server is now ready to accept
> > connections on port 6379
> ```

The dump.rdb file is 1.5GB, and there is ~5GB free RAM(Which is enough i think).

I notcied the free RAM reduced from 5GB to 0 when Redis was loading DB. After it was killed the free RAM became 5GB again.

Why 1.5GB dump.rdb needs 5GB RAM, is it a bug?
How to solve this problem? I don't want to remove the current dump.rdp, there is some important data.

OS Version: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64bit

Redis Version: 2.6.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the dump.rdb is not 1:1 with the RAM usage. See [**Why a 500MB Redis dump.rdb file takes about 5.0GB memory?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243701/why-a-500mb-redis-dump-rdb-file-takes-about-5-0gb-memory).

Redis seems to have been killed by the [**OOM**](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

> It is the job of the linux 'oom killer' to sacrifice one or more
>   processes in order to free up memory for the system when all else
>   fails. It will also kill any process sharing the same mm_struct as the
>   selected process, for obvious reasons.

If your Redis dataset is bigger than the available RAM, in your case, the OOM will try to free up memory and kill it. You can either disable the OOM on Redis:

> Any particular process leader may be immunized against the oom killer
>   if the value of its /proc//oomadj is set to the constant
>   OOM_DISABLE (currently defined as -17).

...see [**How to Configure the Linux Out-of-Memory Killer**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) but your server will start to swap if not enough free memory is available.

So you may want to use tools like [**redis-rdb-tool**](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) or [**rdb2csv**](https://github.com/meou/rdb2csv) to analyze and export valuable data or to use a server with more memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can we set the max RAM size the Redis server can use? e.g. 4GB. If the dataset is bigger than 4GB, then save the new data into Disk. Redis is known as RAM + Disk, could it be that disk is just for storing dump data?

Comment: Yes you can set the max RAM sie with the `maxmemory`
` maxmemory-policy` parameters in redis configuration file.

Comment: "Redis is known as RAM + Disk" not exactly, Redis is memory database only (all the dataset must live in memory), disk is only used for persistence.

Comment: Can i use Swap to avoid such problem?

Comment: Humm that's really not a good idea, swapping will make your system really really slow (if not unstable).